# Percentage calculation of rows

Tags: excel, vba, percentage

Need help on Percentage calculation of rows..

[image]

This is what I'm trying to create but not sure if this actually works..

I want to loop the percentage calculation in all the rows from column B to the last column that the data exists..

```
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PT")
    startCol = "B"
    startRow = 16
    lastRow2 = ws.Range(startCol & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol2 = ws.Cells(3, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol2)
    
        Set rng = ws.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow2)

    For Each cell In rng
    
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-1]C/R[-3]C)"
    Selection.Style = "Percent"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
      
    Next cell
```

```
Edit... I've modified my script now but the looping is not happening.. I mean it is not going to each cell till the last column. Can anyone suggest ??
```

Edit: It is fine now.. I have added below line to exit my loop and it is working fine without any issues..
lastRow2 = lastRow2 + 1

Comment: Could you not paste the code as text rather than an image?  Also, you need to clarify on what exactly you're trying to do and where your error/problem actually is.

Comment: Have you actually run the code, surely you would know if it works if you have?  Just glancing at it and you set 'k' on the 3rd line, but you're already trying to use it in the first row in 'Columns(k)'.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine now. I have added the below line to exit my loop and it is working fine without any issues.

```
lastRow2 = lastRow2 + 1
```